# Find all possible mongodb combinations of two fields

Tags: javascript, arrays, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have in database the next array of objects

```
[
  {
     price: "1"
     type: "buy",
  },
  {
     price: "2"
     type: "buy",
  },
  {
     price: "3"
     type: "sell"
  },
  {
     price: "4"
     type: "sell"
  }
]
```

How can I make an aggregation **to get an array of arrays with all possible combinations** (price could be random number)

**hide items with the highest buy price**

and sort them, so the items with the largest price difference are at the top

```
[
  [
      {
         price: "1"
         type: "buy",
      },
      {
         price: "4"
         type: "sell"
      }
  ],
  [
      {
         price: "1"
         type: "buy",
      },
      {
         price: "3"
         type: "sell"
      },
  ],
  [
      {
         price: "2"
         type: "buy",
      },
      {
         price: "4"
         type: "sell"
      }
  ],
  [
      {
         price: "2"
         type: "buy",
      },
      {
         price: "3"
         type: "sell"
      },
  ],
]
```

Comment: `hide items with the highest buy price` --> this means the `buy` with `price` = `2` must be **`HIDDEN`**; yet the sorted result shows this (ie, it is not hidden). Please clarify if you only need it to be sorted, and not hidden.

Comment: I don't think this is a good use of aggregation.   You need to visit all the information in order to create the combinations so the database isn't really helping you here; in fact, *creating* data is the opposite of what DBs (any DB) are good for.  I recommend just dragging the array to the client side and using the language of your choice to build the combos and do the sort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Query

- self-lookup and match if not same id (avoid same item on pair)
- map to add to the join result the parent item (the pair will always have as first member the one with the biggest price (needed for later))
- unwind pairs
- group pairs to remove the duplicates (each pair will appear 2 times, but its sorted from the map so we can group by it)
- find the price difference, sort by descending, unset the field

*i am not sure it does all you need, because i didn't understand the part `hide items with the highest buy price` the highest buy price is "2" and in your results you have this items

[Playmongo](https://cmql.org/playmongo/?q=628fb02f853f039c69b0f903)

```js
coll.aggregate(
[{"$lookup": 
   {"from": "coll",
    "pipeline": 
     [{"$match": {"$expr": {"$ne": ["$$id", "$_id"]}}},
       {"$project": {"_id": 0, "price": 1, "type": 1}}],
    "as": "pairs",
    "let": {"id": "$_id"}}},
 {"$project": 
   {"_id": 0,
    "pairs": 
     {"$map": 
       {"input": "$pairs",
        "in": 
         {"$cond": 
           [{"$gt": ["$$this.price", "$price"]},
             [{"price": "$price", "type": "$type"}, "$$this"],
             ["$$this", {"price": "$price", "type": "$type"}]]}}}}},
 {"$unwind": "$pairs"}, {"$group": {"_id": "$pairs"}},
 {"$project": {"_id": 0, "pair": "$_id"}},
 {"$set": 
   {"priceDifference": 
     {"$abs": 
       {"$subtract": 
         [{"$toDouble": 
             {"$getField": 
               {"field": "price", "input": {"$arrayElemAt": ["$pairs", 0]}}}},
           {"$toDouble": 
             {"$getField": 
               {"field": "price",
                "input": {"$arrayElemAt": ["$pairs", 1]}}}}]}}}},
 {"$sort": {"priceDifference": -1}},
 {"$unset": ["priceDifference"]}])
```

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with `Playmongo`.  After clicking on your link, where/how are the results shown?

Comment: if you put the mouse in the end of each stage, you see the in/out of that stage, to run all the query, put the mouse in the end of the query, queries are autorun(there is button also to make them run with 2x click and not auto) (i will update it to autorun after query load for new people, thanks for feedback)